# Why does precision decrease after increasing PrecisionGoal and WorkingPrecision on this integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to calculate a messy double-integral to many digits of precision. As shown below, the precision seems to increase reliably as `WorkingPrecision` goes from 16 to 19. Then starting at 20, the result changes in the 5th decimal place. I know that `PrecisionGoal` automatically adjusts to be 10 less than `WorkingPrecision` if not set explicitly, which makes the behavior shown below even more surprising.

```
example[pg_, wp_, mei_: 2000, mr_: Automatic] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x^(-3/2) 1/(E^(x 6000) - 1) Exp[-x (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - 300)^2],
  {x, 1/600^2, 2/600^2, 10/600^2, 100/600^2, 
   1000/600^2, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, 
   Max[0, Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]] - 5/x], Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]], 
   Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]] + 5/x, \[Infinity]},
  PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> mei}, 
  MaxRecursion -> mr]
```

The messy region of integration helps `NIntegrate` concentrate on sharp peaks in the integrand, which I found to be necessary when testing this and similar integrals.`

`example[Automatic, 16] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {0.652093, 5.9530743389378723807348355`16.*^6} ``

`example[Automatic, 17] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {1.45922, 5.95307736376147057651280734657987836949437727`17.*^6} ``

`example[Automatic, 18] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {2.85708, 5.9530773815454329104019275283442228729775598`18.*^6} ``

`example[Automatic, 19] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {6.62376, 5.95307738195314821215051085537129726640733153`19.*^6} ``

`example[Automatic, 20] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {16.2174, 5.95328982429028003608422815664470280663696859`20.*^6} ``

The previous line shows that the something breaks at `WorkingPrecision->20` because the 5th digit suddenly changes.

`example[10, 30] // InputForm // Timing`

`` {15.5158, 5.95328982429028003608422815664470280665446132`30.*^6} ``

The above line shows that it is really increasing `PrecisionGoal` to 10 that breaks something, and that increasing `WorkingPrecision` at this value of `PrecisionGoal` doesn't help.

I would like to be able to reliably compute this integral with up to 20 digits of precision. Any ideas what's causing this problem and how to fix it? I tried changing with the settings `MaxErrorIncreases` and `MaxRecursion` to no avail.

Comment: @MichaelE2 in that line, the previously consistent `5.9530...` becomes `5.9532...`, a sudden change in the 5th digit after increasing from 9-digit precision to 10-digit precision.

Comment: Yes, sorry I added the last line after writing that part. The last line was intended to show that increasing `WorkingPrecision` while holding `PrecisionGoal` fixed doesn't solve the problem. I'll update the post.

Comment: Add `MinRecursion -> 3` and you'll get a bigger shock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look at the integrand (plotting with a change of variables to tangent, so that we can see the integrand at infinity), we notice that the support is mainly concentrated in a small section of a corner.  A more judicious change of variables (on the left) scales the spike to cover most of the domain.  This suggests the second change of variables might help the integration.

```
Plot3D[x^(-3/2) 1/(E^(x 6000) - 1) Exp[-x (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - 300)^2] Dt@
      x*Dt@y /.
    {x -> Tan[s], y -> Tan[Pi/2 - t]} /. _Dt -> 1 // 
  Evaluate,
 {s, 1/600^2 // ArcTan[#] &, Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Ticks -> {Table[{ArcTan[x], x}, {x, {0, 0.5, 1, 2, 10, Infinity}}], 
   Table[{Pi/2 - ArcTan[y], y}, {y, {0, 0.5, 1, 2, 10, Infinity}}], 
   Automatic}]

Plot3D[x^(-3/2) 1/(E^(x 6000) - 1) Exp[-x (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - 300)^2] Dt@
      x*Dt@y /.
    {x -> Tan[s]/600^2, 
     y -> Tan[Pi/2 - t] 200} /. _Dt -> 1 // Evaluate,
 {s, 1/600^2 // ArcTan[600^2 #] &, Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Ticks -> {Table[{ArcTan[600^2 x], 
     x}, {x, {0, 3.*^-6, 5.*^-6, 7.*^-6, 1.*^-5, 2.*^-5, Infinity}}], 
   Table[{Pi/2 - ArcTan[y/200], 
     y}, {y, {0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Infinity}}], Automatic}]
```

[image]
[image]

Here are two helper functions, which are slight modifications of the OP's `example[]` function.  The first does the integral like the OP's, but with the ability to specify the integration rule via the suboption `Method` as well as other options.

```
(* Like the OP's original example[] but with Method and options *)
example2[pg_, wp_, mei_ : 2000, mr_ : Automatic, meth_ : Automatic, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x^(-3/2) 1/(E^(x 6000) - 1) Exp[-x (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - 300)^2],
  {x, 1/600^2, 2/600^2, 10/600^2, 100/600^2, 
   1000/600^2, ∞},
  {y, 0, Max[0, Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]] - 5/x], Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]], 
   Abs[Sqrt[300^2 - 1]] + 5/x, ∞},
  PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> mei, 
    Method -> meth}, MaxRecursion -> mr, opts]

(* With tangent substitutions for x and y *)
example3[pg_, wp_, mei_ : 2000, mr_ : Automatic, meth_ : Automatic, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x^(-3/2) 1/(E^(x 6000) - 1) Exp[-x (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - 300)^2] Dt@x * Dt@y /.
      {x -> Tan[s]/600^2, y -> 200 Tan[Pi/2 - t]} /.
     _Dt ->  1 // Evaluate,
  {t, Pi/2, 0},
  {s, 1/600^2 // ArcTan[600^2 #] &, Pi/2},
  PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> mei, 
    Method -> meth}, MaxRecursion -> mr, opts]
```

Neither result in the OP seems accurate.  The true value appears to be close to $1.5 \times 10^7$.  The OP tried (in effect) to address this problem by a manual subdivision of the interval, but more than that is needed.  That can be obtained by increasing the order of the integration rule or the minimum number of subdivisions.

```
example2[Automatic, MachinePrecision, 2000, 
   20, {"GaussKronrod", "Points" -> 9}, MinRecursion -> 0] // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.089678, 8.268709756340054*^6}  *)

example2[Automatic, MachinePrecision, 2000, 
   20, {"GaussKronrod", "Points" -> 9}, MinRecursion -> 1] // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.161061, 1.5367709045839794`*^7}  *)

example2[Automatic, MachinePrecision, 2000, 20, Automatic, 
   MinRecursion -> 5] // InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.36757, 1.5367709116318425`*^7}  *)
```

With the tangent substitutions, no special subdivision is needed for `NIntegrate` to hone in on the correct value.  The cartesian product of Gauss-Kronrod rules seems to consistently outperform the multidimensional rule (which is the usual `Automatic` rule chosen for a multiple integral).

```
example3[Automatic, MachinePrecision, 2000, 20, "GaussKronrod"] // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.026507, 1.5367708664590633`*^7}  *)

(res20 = example3[20, 40, 2000, 20, "GaussKronrod"]) // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{9.09103, 
 1.536770897940587986735671340147671576809806580607507...`40.*^7}
*)

(res25 = example3[25, 50, 2000, 20, "GaussKronrod"]) // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{13.7239,
 1.536770897940587986735671340149774119056152243104002...`50.*^7}
*)

(res30 = example3[30, 60, 2000, 20, "GaussKronrod"]) // 
  InputForm // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{24.4783, 
 1.536770897940587986735671340149774119156342012210349...`60.*^7}
*)
```

Check the relative error:

```
({res20, res25} - res30)/res30
(*  {-1.368156014*10^-30, -6.51949937630*10^-38}  *)
```

The integral seems to be converging and have at least 20, 25, 30 digits of accuracy, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for this unexpectedly thorough answer! Upon experimenting with this answer, I realized I made the dumb mistake of not subdividing my `y` region correctly: the two places where I had a `5/x` should instead be `Sqrt[5/x]`. This partly resolves my problem, but your solution is still more accurate and orders of magnitude faster, so very much worthwhile.

Comment: Interesting for a novice like me to see how much changing variables can affect computation.

Comment: @WillG You're welcome. I often solve such problems as this by inserting division points like `Sqrt[5/x]`.  One thing to keep in mind is that for (nonoscillatory) integrals over an infinite domain, *Mathematica* will choose a change of variables that maps the infinite domain to finite one, but it does not examine the integrand to figure out what a good one might be.