# plotting plot $(- \infty, x]$ for any arbitrary $x$?

Tags: plotting, graphics, machine-learning

is it possible to plot $(- \infty, x]$ for any arbitrary $x$ on wolfram online? is it possible provide commands?

I am trying to understand the concept of [Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vapnik-ChervonenkisDimension.html).

Comment: No. No finite system can handle plotting an infinite quantity. You will have to provide more details to even try to answer your question.

Comment: I plotted over $[0, \infty)^2$ here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222911/4999  --  is that what you're after?

Comment: I don't see how this question is specific to [tag:wolfram-cloud]. The solution should be the same on any platform.  (That's why I removed the tag.)

Comment: I try to understand VC dimension of lines parallel to $x$ or $y$ axis. I think with myself that for example if $x=5$ this lines be parallel with $y$ axis. I try to understand VC dimension of it. @MichaelE2

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vapnik-ChervonenkisDimension.html

Comment: It would be more helpful if you included a concrete example of what you wanted to plot.

Comment: Maybe what you want are [`HalfLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfLine.html) and [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html)?

Comment: would you please provide both of them as an answer? @MichaelE2

Comment: Do you want the answer to be simply "`HalfLine` and `InfiniteLine`"?

Comment: @MichaelE2 sure.

Comment: Thanks.  I added an answer.  I wasn't sure that I had the right idea.  I also added the [tag:graphics] tag.  I think that if `HalfLine` etc. are the right answer, then you'll be using `Graphics` more that `Plot` and its kin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs683/2008sp/lecture%20notes/683notes_0428.pdf, which is linked on [the MathWorld link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vapnik-ChervonenkisDimension.html) in [a comment by the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236014/plotting-plot-infty-x-for-any-arbitrary-x/236057#comment595994_236014), I inferred that what was desired was the illustration of the following concept. I will us the interval $(-\infty, r]$ instead of the OP's notation so as not to conflict with the notation in the definitions:

> A set system $(x, S)$ consists of a set $x$ in the definition along with a collection of subsets of $x$. A subset...$A ⊆ x$ is **shattered** by $S$ if each subset of $A$ can be expressed as the intersection of $A$ with a subset in $S$.
>
> **VC-dimension** of a set system is the cardinality of the largest subset of $A$ that can be shattered.

**1D**: There isn't much detail in the OP.  If the set $x$ is the set of real numbers and $S$ is the collection of intervals $(-\infty, r]$, then the intervals may be represented by
[`HalfLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfLine.html).

*Update:* Here's a way to visualize the concept with `NumberLinePlot` and "plot $(-\infty,r]$":

```
SeedRandom[0];
Block[{r, s, A},
 A = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 3];
 r = Mean[A];
 s = Interval[{-Infinity, r}];
 NumberLinePlot[{s, A}, PlotLegends -> {"s", "A"}]
 ]
```

[image]

A 3-element $A$ cannot be shattered since the only subsets that may be obtained are the empty set, $\{\,x_1\,\}$, $\{\,x_1,x_2\,\}$, and $\{\,x_1,x_2,x_3\,\}$.  (The VC dimension is $1$, I believe.)

**2D**: If $x$ is the real plane and $S$ consists of half-planes
$\{\,(a,b) \mathrel{|} a < r\,\}$,
then [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) and
[`HalfPlane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfPlane.html) may be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can plot a function over an infinite domain, by coming up with a function that compresses that domain to a finite interval.

For example, plotting Sin[x] in the interval (−∞,5] by scaling the domain with
x |-> 5*2 x/(x + 1)

(-1 maps to −∞, 0 maps to 0, 1 maps to 5)

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

Plot[f[5* 2 x/(x + 1)], {x, -1, 1}, Ticks -> {{{-1, "-\[Infinity]"}, {1, "5"}}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this

```
x=5;
Plot[Sin[t], t ∈ ImplicitRegion[-∞ < t <= x, t]]
```

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[t], t ∈ ImplicitRegion[-∞ < t <= x, t], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {{x, 5}, -50, 10}]
```